# QSqlDatabase check the data base already exist

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I need to sore some value on my system locally and access it later in table format, so I chose QSqlDatabase. And as a first I have to check the database already exist. But using the below code I am always getting the message `Data base not exist creating new....` what can be the problem ?

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include "QFile"
#include "QDebug"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString dbName = "lprDB";
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

    if( QFile::exists(dbName))
    {
         qDebug()<<"Data base exist....";
    }
    else {
        qDebug()<<"Data base not exist creating new....";
        db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: May be the problem here is that you do not actually create a database?

Comment: Yes I understood, I have to call `db.open()`, for creating the DB

Comment: Not sure if opening is enough. Anyway you would need to create some db schema in order to use it.

Comment: You mean I have to add some table to DB.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Tables, triggers, views...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the points, I will take care about it.

Comment: Hi I would like to ask you one more thing, does the `db.open()` overwrite if the database already there?.

Comment: No. it just opens the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Armatel, you should open the db, that will create the db file.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>  
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include "QFile"
#include "QDebug"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString dbName = "lprDB";
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

    if( QFile::exists(dbName))
    {
        qDebug()<<"Data base exist....";
    }
    else {
        qDebug()<<"Data base not exist creating new....";
        db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
        db.open(); // <<< Add this!

        if(!db.isOpen()) {
            qDebug() << "ERROR: could not open database";
        }
        qDebug() << "DB opened";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably addDatabase created the database to different directory than the QFile::exists checks.

My understanding is that the QSqlDatabase creates the database to the standard data location folder which can be get following way:

```
QStringList dataLocations = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);
QString dataLocationPath =  dataLocations.at(0);
```

So, perhaps checking

```
QFile::exists(dataLocationPath+"/"+dbName)
```

helps?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay, I got it working when I call db.open().